# How to create an Authentication middleware for a Flutter app?

Tags: authentication, middleware, flutter-getx, react-state-management, obs

This is my `home.dart` code and I want to write an Authentication Middleware for my app. At the moment my `main.dart` code looks like this:

```
void main() {
  Get.put(MenuController());
  Get.put(NavigationController());
  Get.put(AuthController());
  Get.put(AuthCard);
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Obx(() => GetMaterialApp(
          initialRoute: AuthController.instance.isAuth
              ? homeScreenRoute
              : authenticationScreenRoute,
          unknownRoute: GetPage(
              name: '/not-found',
              page: () => PageNotFound(),
              transition: Transition.fadeIn),
          getPages: [
            GetPage(
                name: rootRoute,
                page: () {
                  return SiteLayout();
                }),
            GetPage(
                name: authenticationScreenRoute,
                page: () => const AuthenticationScreen()),
            GetPage(name: homeScreenRoute, page: () => const HomeScreen()),
          ],
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: 'BasicCode',
          theme: ThemeData(
            scaffoldBackgroundColor: light,
            textTheme: GoogleFonts.mulishTextTheme(Theme.of(context).textTheme)
                .apply(bodyColor: Colors.black),
            pageTransitionsTheme: const PageTransitionsTheme(builders: {
              TargetPlatform.iOS: FadeUpwardsPageTransitionsBuilder(),
              TargetPlatform.android: FadeUpwardsPageTransitionsBuilder(),
            }),
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

And the `isAuth` variable that I checking at the `initialRoute` part of the code comes from the following line of codes, inside the `auth_controller` file that extends `GetXController`:

```
final _isAuth = false.obs;

bool get isAuth {
 _isAuth.value= token != null;
 return _isAuth.value;
}

  String? get token {
    if (_expiryDate != null &&
        _expiryDate!.isAfter(DateTime.now()) &&
        _token != null) {
      return _token;
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Everything seems good but the application sticks at the authentication page and won't move to home screen after the `isAuth`'s value changed to true!

I searched for that and found another way by creating an authentication middleware. So I added the following code bellow the above code inside the `main.dart` file:

```
class AuthMiddlware extends GetMiddleware {
  @override
  RouteSettings? redirect(String route) => !AuthController.instance.isAuth
      ? const RouteSettings(name: authenticationScreenRoute)
      : null;
}
```

But I get a red line under the `redirect` word with no error decription and don't know how to complete the middleware and make it work?

Comment: `(String route)` should be `(String? route)`. Also, see my other answer.

Answer (score 4):

Example of how to implement an AuthGuard with FirebaseAuth and Getx.

(If not using FirebaseAuth, swap it to your preferred authentication provider in `AuthGuardMiddleware`.)

**middleware.dart**

```dart
import 'auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class AuthGuardMiddleware extends GetMiddleware {
  var authService = Get.find<AuthService>();

  @override
  RouteSettings? redirect(String? route) {
    return authService.isLoggedIn() ? null : RouteSettings(name: '/login');
  }
}
```

**auth.dart**

```dart
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class AuthService extends GetxService {
  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  bool isLoggedIn() {
    return _firebaseAuth.currentUser != null;
  }

  // IMPLEMENT additional FirebaseAuth methods here.
}
```

**main.dart**

```dart
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'middleware.dart';
...
GetPage(  
  name: '/protected',
  page: () => Protected()),
  middlewares: [
    AuthGuardMiddleware(),
  ]),
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy paste :)

```
class AuthMiddlware extends GetMiddleware {
      @override
      RouteSettings? redirect(String? route) => !AuthController.instance.isAuth
          ? const RouteSettings(name: authenticationScreenRoute)
          : null;
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Where should I put the code? Where/how to use it?