# GetX middleware runs before binding?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

Here is my Auth middleware:

```
import 'package:donirajkrv/controllers/user_controller.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class AuthMiddleware extends GetMiddleware {
  final authService = Get.find<UserController>().isUserLogged; // Here is error, this line can't find UserController
  @override
  int? get priority => 1;
  bool isAuthenticated = false;

  @override
  RouteSettings? redirect(String? route) {
    isAuthenticated = true;
    if (isAuthenticated == false) {
      return const RouteSettings(name: '/login');
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

A line from above (where is my comment) returns me an error:

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following message was thrown building MyApp(dirty):
"UserController" not found. You need to call "Get.put(UserController())" or "Get.lazyPut(()=>UserController())"

The relevant error-causing widget was
MyApp
lib/main.dart:9
```

And middleware makes me that error.

```
...
 GetMaterialApp(
      initialBinding: UserBinding(),
...
```

I have tried to fix this with:

```
GetPage(
      name: '/${Routes.HOME_PAGE}',
      page: () => const HomePage(),
      binding: UserBinding(),
      middlewares: [AuthMiddleware()])
```

But again same error.

Answer (score 0):

I am here again, with a solution at this time :P

Please add this static method in your user_controller.dart file

```
static UserController get findOrInitialize{
    try{
      return Get.find<UserController>();
    }catch(e){
      //get controller is not initialized yet
      Get.put(UserController());
      return Get.find<UserController>();
    }
  }
```

In the initiation of the controller in user_bindings.dart file

instead of

```
@override
void dependencies() {
    UserController()
  }
```

do it like this:

```
@override
  void dependencies() {
    UserController.findOrInitialize;
  }
```

Finally, in the auth_middleware.dart file

initiate your controller like the example below:

```
final authService = UserController.findOrInitialize;
```

You can find the whole example here: https://github.com/Prosa/Flutter-GetX-Bindings-Example

Comment: May you also help on this question?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70727549/how-to-create-an-authentication-middleware-for-a-flutter-app/71729168#71729168

Comment: I saw your problem. I think that you can follow my example on github, download it and run it to check how it works, if you have any further questions, let me know, I will post a thorough answer.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I downloaded your code but I don't know why it gives me errors for all the import packages.

Comment: @ensan3kamel maybe you need to upgrade your flutter version

Comment: I could run your code but couldn't properly understand how to apply it to my problem? Or even it is my problem's solution or not?

Comment: I think just moving the line `Get.put<UserBinding>(UserBinding());` solves the problem with less code. Please see refer to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

The Middleware gets initialized before the Binding. (As to why this happens should be discussed with `Getx`.)

**Solution**

Move the Binding out of the method call `initialBinding` and place it somewhere else. This solution is a bit hacky, but **solves the problem with one line of code**.

**Code Before**

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return GetMaterialApp(
      initialBinding: UserBinding(),
    ...
```

**Code After**

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 
    Get.put<UserBinding>(UserBinding()); // ADDED

    return GetMaterialApp(
      // initialBinding: UserBinding(),    REMOVED
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this by initializing the controller in the middleware file.

```
class AuthMiddleware extends GetMiddleware {

  @override
  RouteSettings redirect(String route) {
    final authService = Get.find<AuthService>();
    Get.put(RootController(), permanent: true); // here
    if (!authService.isAuth) {
      return RouteSettings(name: Routes.LOGIN);
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this by wrapper `GetMaterialApp` as `GetXMaterialApp`.

You can find the whole code snap here, please click link:

[Fix GetX middleware runs before binding. by wrapper GetMaterialApp as GetXMaterialApp.](https://gist.github.com/woodjobber/020096192da4a1038508b99af757dd86)

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
static UserController get findOrInitialize{

  return Get.isRegistered<UserController>() ? Get.find<UserController>(): Get.put(UserController());}
```